# Data structure challenge Tree DFS

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

I came across an interesting coding challenge and could use help with the best way to do it. Here's the challenge :

It’s a brilliant day while our smart frog prince went on his quest to collect the golden eggs from the castles to break the curse and become the real prince again. He can start with (any) one of the castle tower’s topmost floor where he sees more towers nearby and the fairy sends him a message(input) on location of the golden eggs. He has the power to jump across towers any number of times until he reaches the bottom floor(ground floor) however he cannot climb up again under any circumstances.

While he jumps within the same tower, he can go to the floor below, but if he jumps from one tower to any another tower, he will drop by two floors. Say, if our frog prince is in the 1st tower’s 5th floor and if he wants to jump to the 4th tower, he will lose height (two floors) and land at 4th tower’s 3rd floor. There can be any number of floors for a castle tower, all castle towers will have equal number of floors.

**Input Format**

Input starts with N value: the number of castle towers.

These are followed by N number of lines,

the first integer in a line indicates the number of eggs in that respective tower,
the following integers indicate the egg’s floor wise position in the tower, also there can be more than one egg on a floor.

Sample Input:

```
3    
5 1 1 1 4 10    
8 9 5 7 7 3 9 8 8    
5 9 5 6 4 3
```

Sample output:

```
12
```

Explanation:

[image]

**I need help with the DFS (Or any other algorithm) part of the code.**

Comment: Could you share the problem link...?

Comment: So what have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share YOUR findings. Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Data structure coding challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63242242/data-structure-coding-challenge)

Answer (score 0):

Try dynamic programming.

1. Build a graph from the data. the graph will be a DAG (there can't be circles)
2. do topological sort on the graph
3. go over the nodes (floors) in the topological order. for each node, calculate the max number of eggs collected up to the node. the value is the max over all it's predecessors plus it's own value.